# Excel Pivot Table Calculated Field including LEN

Tags: pivot-table, worksheet-function

I'd like to setup a pivot table field that counts the number of characters in a given field.  LEN([field name]) only returns 1 for every row.

Comment: returns 1 what for every row?

Comment: I agree that SUM of LEN(fieldname) returns 1 on every row.

Comment: May have to do with calculated fields interpreting content as values prior to performing the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done (sorry!), text values in calculated fields are treated as `0` automatically.